# Jasypt EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException

Tags: java, encryption, client-server, nio, jasypt

A few days ago, I asked a question regarding a problem I had with Jasypt. I referenced a larger program throwing the EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException. Well, I still can't figure out the problem. Here's what's happening: (and this provides insight in to how it works:)

```
Step 1: Connection
Client Connects
Server Callback: connection(Selection key)
Server Sends Cipher
    Client Receives Cipher
Sends encrypted "connection" message  "YYPgDOGffgxu6aahZyNSgw=="
    Client Receives Encrypted msg "YYPgDOGffgxu6aahZyNSgw=="
    Client Throws EncryptionOperationNotPossibleExcepton
        at line 45
```

This is really purplexing.  It's likely that there's a problem with character encodings, but I'm not sure. The server and client are running on the same computer at the moment and I'm pretty sure I'm using US-ASCII throughout. Here is the relevant code:

Here's the client:

```
public static String CHAR_ENC_B = "US-ASCII";
public static String cipher = null;

public static void main(String[] argv) throws UnknownHostException {
    final BasicTextEncryptor textEncryptor = new BasicTextEncryptor();
    AbstractBlockingClient client = new AbstractBlockingClient(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"),4444) {
        @Override
        protected void messageReceived(ByteBuffer message) {
            if (cipher==null) {
                cipher=bb2str(message); 
                textEncryptor.setPassword(cipher);
                System.out.println("Cipher(20):"+cipher);}
            else {
                System.out.println("Raw Message(22):"+bb2str(message));
                System.out.println("Decrypted(23):"+textEncryptor.decrypt(bb2str(message)));
                String tosend = textEncryptor.encrypt("Test Reply");
                try {
                    this.write(textEncryptor.encrypt("Test Reply").getBytes(CHAR_ENC_B));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void disconnected() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void connected(boolean alreadyConnected) {

        }
    };
    client.run();
}
```

Here is the server:

```
public static String CHAR_ENC_B = "US-ASCII";
public static void main(String[] argv) {
//Create the server:
    AbstractServer server = new AbstractServer(4444) {
        @Override
        protected void messageReceived(ByteBuffer message, SelectionKey key) {
            System.out.println("Recieved Raw Message(18):"+bb2str(message));
            System.out.println("Recieved Decrypted Message(19):"+decrypt_string(getCS(key).ekey,bb2str(message)));
            ClientSelector replacement = process_message(decrypt_string(getCS(key).ekey,bb2str(message)),getCS(key));
            key.attach(replacement);
        }
        @Override
        protected void connection(SelectionKey key) {
            ClientSelector newone = new ClientSelector(key,"","","");
            newone.ip = ((SocketChannel)key.channel()).socket().getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
            key.attach(newone);
            this.write(key,newone.ekey.getBytes());
            String tosend = encrypt_string(newone.ekey,"a");
            this.write(key,tosend.getBytes());
            System.out.println("Cipher:"+newone.ekey);
            System.out.println("Encrypted String Sent(34):"+tosend);
        }
        @Override
        protected void disconnected(SelectionKey key) {

        }
        @Override
        protected void started(boolean alreadyStarted) {
            System.out.println("SERVER STARTED");
        }
        @Override
        protected void stopped() {

        }
    };
    server.run();
}
public static String decrypt_string(String key, String msg) {
    BasicTextEncryptor textEncryptor = new BasicTextEncryptor();
    textEncryptor.setPassword(key);
    return textEncryptor.decrypt(msg);
}
public static String encrypt_string(String key, String msg) {
    BasicTextEncryptor textEncryptor = new BasicTextEncryptor();
    textEncryptor.setPassword(key);
    return textEncryptor.encrypt(msg);
}
```

These aren't actually the messages that are going to be sent, but it is a good place to start.

Some information: `ClientSelector` is a class that allows the server to identify who it's talking to (with username, password, ip, etc.) and `bb2str` converts `ByteBuffer` to `String`.

Any help would really be appreciated. I hope it's not a stupid mistake like the last one!
Thank you.

**EDIT:** I've added the code for bb2str:

```
public static String bb2str(ByteBuffer bytebuff) {
    byte[] bytearr = new byte[bytebuff.remaining()];
    bytebuff.get(bytearr);
    String s = null;
    try {s = new String(bytearr,"US-ASCII");} 
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return s;
}
```

Comment: The base 64 output is correctly retrieved from the buffer up to the end by the `bb2str()` method? Could you post the implementation?

Comment: What does the documentation say about possible causes of the EncryptionOperationNotPossibleExcepton?  Have you checked all the listed possible causes?

Comment: The documentation is really vague about the EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException. It purposely doesn't share any error details for security reasons. It says this exception is raised when there is an exception with the Java side of encryption. It's really general. @owlstead - I'll post the code to bb2str, but we know it works because both the client and the server know the cipher - that's transmitted perfectly. So I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: I added bb2str() for you @owlstead.

Comment: I think that it does what it says on the tin. Hint though: try to replace that default `e.printStackTrace()` with a `throw new IllegalStateException(e)` within your IDE and your life becomes a whole lot easier. Don't return `null` on failure, whatever you do. Oh, and [this may come in useful](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#decode(java.nio.ByteBuffer)), safes you a buffer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

Here's the thing... the implementation of `bb2str()` I wrote here seems to empty the bytebuffer. So I can only call `bb2str` once. If I call it more than once then I'll end up with an empty string and that screws up jayspt because in the code:

```
if (this.saltGenerator.includePlainSaltInEncryptionResults()) {
        // Check that the received message is bigger than the salt
        if (encryptedMessage.length <= this.saltSizeBytes) {
            throw new EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException();
        }
}
```

And of course `encryptedMessage.length` is going to be  `<= this.saltSizeBytes` if `encryptedMessage.length` is zero and `this.saltSizeBytes` is 8.

It's fixed. The war is over.